# How to display multiline text in treecell xul

Tags: xml, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I tried the following, but it didn't work in my firefox addon:

```
<treerow>
            <treecell label="2ee"><description> This is a long section of text that will word wrap when displayed. </description></treecell>
          </treerow>
```

Comment: Dang man tree's aren't my specialty :( But lets give @WladamirPalant a call. Calling Wlad! :p

Answer (score 0):

Download Remote XUL Manager addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remote-xul-manager/

Then go to Ted's XUL tester. http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/xuledit/xuledit.xul

Paste your code there and shrink window, it wraps fine.